# How to I set the Size Hint for A QTableWidget in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I currently have the python function (below) to build a QTableWidget from a pandas dataframe (df). I would like this QTableWidget to default to a size that shows all cells. Unfortunately, the default Size Hint used by QSizePolicy.Maximum cuts off some of the rows and columns in the table. QTableWidget does not appear to have a setSizeHint() method. How do I set the size hint to a the size that shows all rows and columns?

I've tried looking for previous posts about this, but none of the answers I've found are in Python and use QTableWidget.

```
import PyQt5.QWidgets as QWidgets
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
import PyQt5.QtGui as QtGui
import pandas as pd

def build_table(self,df):

    table = QWidgets.QTableWidget()

    table.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
    table.setRowCount(len(df.index))
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

    for row_num, row in enumerate(df.index):
        for col_num, col in enumerate(df.columns):
            item = QWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(df.loc[row,col]))
            item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
    table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    table.resizeRowsToContents()    
    table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
    table.setSizePolicy(QWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum,QWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sizeAdjustPolicy : SizeAdjustPolicy**

This property holds the policy describing how the size of the scroll area changes when the size of the viewport changes.

Try it:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)    

        self.tableWidget = self.build_table(df)

        self.tableWidget.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)      # <---

        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)   

        layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Button"))        

    def build_table(self, df):

        table = QTableWidget()
        table.setColumnCount(len(df.columns))
        table.setRowCount(len(df.index))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

        for row_num, row in enumerate(df.index):
            for col_num, col in enumerate(df.columns):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(df.loc[row,col]))

                table.setItem(row_num, col_num, item)                              # +++

                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        table.resizeRowsToContents()    
        table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
#        self.table.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum, QSizePolicy.Maximum)        # ---

        return table                                                               # +++


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'a': ['1','2','3','4','Mary','Jim','John'], 'b': ['3','4','1','2',100, 200, 300], 'c': ['1','2','3','4','a','b','c'],
     'd': ['1','2','3','4','Mary','Jim','John'], 'e': ['1','2','3','4',100, 200, 300], 'f': ['1','2','3','4','a','b','c'],
     'g': ['1','2','3','4','Mary','Jim','John'], 'h': ['1','2','3','4',100, 200, 300], 'j': ['1','2','3','4','a','b','c'],
     'k': ['1','2','3','4','Mary','Jim','John'], 'l': ['1','2','3','4',100, 200, 300], 'm': ['1','2','3','4','a','b','c'],
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin(df)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]